# Improving C# code related to dynamic programming

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming

I have this task teacher gave me and I wrote a code which works fine and all. There is this "test area" where you can send that code and it did ok but i know there may be some simple yet important preformance boosts that can be implemented for it to get maximum score but I am not sure which are those. Can someone help?

This is the code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    // Koriscene ASCII vrednosti
    enum Polja { prepreka = 120, praznina = 46, putanja = 1 }
    static HashSet<int> gotoviIndeksi = new HashSet<int>();

    static void RekurzivnoCitanje(List<Polja[]> ispodProzora) {
        var str = Console.ReadLine();
        if (str != null) {
            ispodProzora.Add(str.Select(c => (Polja)c).ToArray());
            RekurzivnoCitanje(ispodProzora);
        }
        else return;
    }

    static bool ValidnoPolje(int i, int j, List<Polja[]> trenutnoStanje) {
        return i >= 0 && i < trenutnoStanje.Count && j >= 0 &&
            j < trenutnoStanje[i].Length && trenutnoStanje[i][j] == Polja.praznina;
    }

    static Tuple<int, int>[] mogucnosti = new Tuple<int, int>[3] {
        new Tuple<int, int>(0, 1),
        new Tuple<int, int>(0, -1),
        new Tuple<int, int>(1, 0)
    };

    static void Popunjavanje(int i, int j, List<Polja[]> trenutnoStanje, int pocetno) {
        if (!ValidnoPolje(i, j, trenutnoStanje)) { return; }

        trenutnoStanje[i][j] = Polja.putanja;
        if(i == trenutnoStanje.Count - 1) {
            gotoviIndeksi.Add(pocetno);
            return;
        }

        if (trenutnoStanje[i + 1][j] == Polja.prepreka) {
            Popunjavanje(i + mogucnosti[0].Item1, j + mogucnosti[0].Item2, trenutnoStanje, pocetno);
            Popunjavanje(i + mogucnosti[1].Item1, j + mogucnosti[1].Item2, trenutnoStanje, pocetno);
        }
        else if (trenutnoStanje[i + 1][j] == Polja.praznina) {
            Popunjavanje(i + mogucnosti[2].Item1, j + mogucnosti[2].Item2, trenutnoStanje, pocetno);
        }
    }

    static void Main() {
        var ispodProzora = new List<Polja[]>();
        RekurzivnoCitanje(ispodProzora);

        for (int i = 0; i < ispodProzora[0].Length; i++) {
            Popunjavanje(0, i, ispodProzora.Select(array => array.ToArray()).ToList(), i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < ispodProzora[0].Length; i++) {
            Console.Write(gotoviIndeksi.Contains(i) ? 1 : )
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Code is written in my language so hopefully you dont mind that.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: _"Code is written in my language so hopefully you dont mind that."_ - not really but it would be _much_ easier if it were in english. So, if you are not sure if your code needs to be read by international audience, write it in english.